# How to access rendered truncated text of element in React component?

Tags: reactjs, components

I have a sidebar where CSS limits the width of a string when rendering.  How can I access the final, rendered string to diff my original prop and the rendered string?

I'm trying this in `componentDidMount` and everything I can access there is the original, complete string.

There is no #id on this element so cannot access that.

Comment: *"CSS limits the width"* -- you mean with `text-overflow: ellipsis` or something?

Comment: Yes exactly right

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there is a way to get at the rendered text after `text-overflow`.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a ref to the node and then use it to access the inner HTML attribute.

```
componentDidMount() {
  const text = this.sidebar.innerHTML
}
render() {
  return (
   <div ref={sidebar => {this.sidebar = sidebar}}>Some text here</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  This doesn't get me the shrunken text though